# Confusion in Proof of "Zorn's Lemma $\implies$ Tukey's Lemma"

Tags: proof-explanation, axiom-of-choice

*Definitions:* A Subset $C$ of a partially order set $(P,<)$ is said to be a **chain** if $C$ is linearly ordered by $<$. $u$ is an **upper bound** of $C$ if $c\le u$ for each $c\in C$. We say that $a\in P$ is a **maximal element** if $a<x$ for no $x\in P$. A family of sets $\mathfrak{F}$ has **finite character** if for any set $X$, $X\in\mathfrak{F}\iff Y\in\mathfrak{F}$ for any finite subset $Y$ of $X$.

1. **Zorn's Lemma**: Let $(P,<)$ be a non-empty partially ordered set with the property that every chain in $P$ has an upper bound. Then $P$ has a maximal element.
2. **Tukey's Lemma**: If a non-empty family of sets $\mathfrak{F}$ has finite character then $\mathfrak{F}$ has a maximal element with respect to the partial order of inclusion ($\subseteq$)

*Proof of $1\implies 2$*: Assume $\mathfrak{F}$ is a non-empty family of sets with fintite character, with partial ordering of inclusion, $\subseteq$. If $\mathcal{C}$ is a chain in $\mathfrak{F}$ and if $A=\bigcup\{X\mid X\in \mathcal{C}\}$, then **every finite subset of $A$ belongs to $\mathfrak{F}$** and therefore $A\in\mathfrak{F}$. Obviously $A$ is an upper bound of $\mathcal{C}$. Hence we can apply Zorn's Lemma and get a maximal element of $\mathfrak{F}$.

***What I do not understand is that why should every finite subset of $A$ belong to $\mathfrak{F}$?*** I mean suppose $X,X'\in\mathcal{C}$ and let $X_1,X_1'$ be finite where $X_1\subseteq X$ and $X_1'\subseteq X'$. Then obviously $X_1$ and $X_1'$ should be in $\mathfrak{F}$ since $\mathfrak{F}$ has finite character. However $X_1\cup X_1'$ is a finite subset of $A$, and how can we guarantee that it is also in $\mathfrak{F}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\cal C$ was a chain, every finite subset of $A$ is a subset of some $X\in\cal C$, but since $X\in\frak F$ by assumption, so must be all of *its* finite subsets.

Therefore every finite subset of $A$ is a finite subset of some $X\in\frak F$, and therefore an element of $\frak F$.

---

The point here is to take the usual argument using Zorn's lemma in almost any conceivable case: you have a compact property, i.e. a property that holds if and only if it holds for finite subsets (linear independence, being a chain or an antichain, etc.) and to test that the "limit object of a given chain" has this property you merely verify that every finite part of this limit object already had it. And how? Just like the above argument goes.

Comment: That is what I am failing to understand, this particular statement: "Since $\cal C$ was a chain, every finite subset of $A$ is a subset of some $X\in\cal C$"

Comment: Either $\cal C$ has a maximal element, in which it's $A$. Or it doesn't, in which case every finite subset is a subset of some element of the chain. The remark I made at the end was meant to direct you to these sort of proofs, e.g. the existence of a basis using Zorn's lemma.

Comment: Okay I think I understood. The example with $X$ and $X'$ that I mentioned in the last paragraph of my question, can be resolved, because either $X\subseteq X'$ or $X'\subseteq X$, as $\cal C$ is a chain